# Two versions of System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, .net

I have difficulties to understand dual existence of System.Net.Http. It exists as a part of .Net Framework 4.7 (in version 4.0.0.0), but is also available as a separate package in much newer version (version 4.3.2 as of now).

Why is it available twofold?
Why latest available version (probably 4.3) has not been included in .Net Framework 4.7 when it was released?

Comment: I had a similar problem and finally noticed that one of the projects in my solution was referencing a version in the GAC on my machine, and another project was referencing a package in Nuget.  Once I installed the same version via Nuget for all projects in my solution, the versioning issue went away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, package version and assembly version can be different versions.

Package System.Net.Http, version 4.3.2: Assembly version is 4.1.1.1

I can't find a released package for System.Net.Http with assembly version 4.0.0.0, so I think that it's not distributed as a package<s>, but there is at least one prerelease package which has that assembly, System.Net.Http, version 4.0.0-beta-22416</s>. It seems that all prerelease packages from version 4.0.0-beta-22416 to version 4.0.1-rc2-24027 have .NET Framework versions of the assembly, with version 4.0.0.0.

.NET Framework 4.7 supports the APIs that exist in System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0 and if you want extra functionality, you can pull extra APIs by installing a newer package, like you would do with any other package.